Formatting Laravel Data
A bit confused. How to convert to one data format
I had to submit this request to the service
class SupportService
{
    public function findUserTicket(int $userId): LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        return Support::where('user_id', $userId)
            ->select('support_id', 'is_closed', 'is_resolved', 'status', 'summary', 'updated_at')
            ->first();
    }
}

there was a need to call this method in another service to process the data
but in the new service I have all the variables in CamelCase and findUserTickets returns in snake_case and there is confusion when working with variables
it turns out that such an entry
$ticket = $this->userService->findUserTicket(); 
$ticketName = $ticket->ticket_name .' - '.$ticket->ticket_id; 
return ['ticketName' => $ticketName] 

is the appropriate sign?
How do you solve this? I would be grateful and thank you

Your findUserTicket is returning the data (and therefore the variable names) in the format of your entity class, as you're basically executing a database query here. It's always not a good idea, to rely on the persistent layer format for other (external) services. So you have to do exactly what you did here, you need to transform your data from the database entity to the neede output format.

first of all findUserTicket returns a Support model not an instance of LengthAwarePaginator

Understood. Thank you. What if my method returns paginate(40) instead of first()? Will it be necessary to convert both data and pagination? or in this case would it be better to return the API Resource from this method or will the API Resource only be returned in the controller?

I does not matter, but model attributes are in snake_case, since usually SQL columns and tables are named that way. Within your code it does not matter what case you use. If you want to change the case for when you return this data in an API response, use a resource class.
